# How can I serve multiple websites from specific paths on Apache?

Tags: linux, apache, server

I have two projects - site_a and site_b - that I would like to host on an Ubuntu server running Apache. I want these two projects to be accessed at paths `{domain}/site_a` and `{domain}/site_b`, respectively; I am not interested in having separate domains for them.

With the exception of each project's `public/` directory, each project contains files that I do not want to be publicly accessible. So, I have stored the projects in `/home` instead of in `/var/www`.

I have tried specifying `ServerName` in both projects' `.conf` files and `<Directory>` in `apache2.conf`, but am unsure on how to make this work. At the moment, whenever I access `{domain}/` in a browser, I get shown the contents of `site_a/public`.

Here is what I tried so far:

site_a.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost/site_a
    DocumentRoot /home/site_a/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

site_b.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost/site_b
    DocumentRoot /home/site_b/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /home/site_a>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/site_b>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want both sites to respond on the same domain, you can only have 1 VirtualHost.  Apache has no way to know what is site A and site B based on the domain if you only have 1.

---

**One domain, 2 sites**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    documentRoot "YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH/apache/htdocs"
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    ErrorLog "logs/80_error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/80_access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Setup your files like this:

- under YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH/apache/htdocs
- `mkdir site_a`: put your files for site a here
- `mkdir site_b`: put your files for site b here

---

**One domain, 2 ports**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SITE A CONFIG
</VirtualHost>

<VirtulaHost *:81>
    SITE B CONFIG
</VirtualHost>
```

To see site a: http://example.com/
To see site b: http://example.com:81/